# How to remove white space "U+3164"?

Tags: java, string, kotlin

My code is checking the blank/empty string using `"".isNullOrBlank()`.

But I faced a very weird case.

`ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ`

Did you see this white spaces?
If you check this using .isNullOrBlank(), it returns false.

I tried to remove it using below code but I couldn't...

```
println("       ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ       ".replace("\\t+".toRegex(), "").isNullOrBlank())
println("       ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ       ".replace("\\n+".toRegex(), "").isNullOrBlank())
println("       ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ       ".replace("\\r+".toRegex(), "").isNullOrBlank())
println("       ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ       ".replace("\\s+".toRegex(), "").isNullOrBlank())
```

This string is consist of white spaces and "U+3164".

So if I use below code, it prints "true"

```
println("       ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ       ".replace("\u3164", "").isNullOrBlank()) // prints true
```

But I don't like this.

I don't know about the unicode world well.
Maybe there are a lot of similar unicodes...
I want to cover all case...

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try copying the value itself in replace method? Looks like there are 3 different values in that sample you provided. Double click on the empty space at the beginning middle and end to highlight different sections.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Non-space_blanks
Looks like that’s considered a ‘non space blank’, not technically white space. Seems like you may have to wrap a library-style method around the extra cases listed on the Wikipedia page.